# RESTful org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0

Tags: java, json, rest, jpa

I am struggling with a problem related to calling a Java RESTful service using JSON.  The RESTful service simply updates a record in a database table using JPA.  The strange thing is that this problem only occurs when I submit a PUT request.  If I use a POST request, it works fine.  I receive the following error from the Server side...

> May 09, 2014 2:40:32 PM
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
>   WARNING: WebApplicationException has been caught :
>   org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin
>   with '{' at character 0 of

There is nothing wrong with the JSON being sent.  The JSON that is being sent is the following...

```
{
    "workflowMilestone": {
        "id": 7,
        "wfId": {
            "id": "1"
        },
        "orderNum": "2",
        "description": "Week 2",
        "completion": "1",
        "completionLengthCode": {
            "lengthCode": "WEEKS"
        }
    }
}
```

To make the call to the RESTful service from the client side, I am making an HttpURLConnection as follows...

```
URL url = new URL(urlStr); // urlStr contains the URL being called
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setRequestMethod("PUT");
httpCon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

OutputStreamWriter output = null;
try {
    output = new OutputStreamWriter(httpCon.getOutputStream());
    output.write(jsonString.trim());
    int responseCode = httpCon.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("PUT Response Code: " + responseCode);
} finally {
    if (output != null) { output.close(); }
}
```

From the server side the RESTful method looks like this...

```
@Path("/rest/wfService")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Stateless(name = "caWorkflowService")
public class WorkflowService extends BaseService {

    ...

    @PUT
    @Path("/updateWfMilestone")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public WorkflowMilestone updateWfMilestone(
            @Context HttpHeaders headers,
            @Context HttpServletRequest request,
            final WorkflowMilestone workflowMilestone) {
        ...

        try {
            ...
            WorkflowMilestone toUpdate = this.getEntityManager().merge(workflowMilestone);

            return toUpdate;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to update WorkflowMilestone record.", iae);
            workflowMilestone.setError("IAE: Unable to update WorkflowMilestone record.");
            return workflowMilestone;
        } catch (EntityExistsException nre) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to create WorkflowMilestone record.", nre);
            workflowMilestone.setError("EEE: Unable to update WorkflowMilestone record.");
            return workflowMilestone;
        } catch (TransactionRequiredException tre) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to update WorkflowMilestone record.", tre);
            workflowMilestone.setError("TRE: Unable to update WorkflowMilestone record.");
            return workflowMilestone;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to update WorkflowMilestone record.", t);
            workflowMilestone.setError("T: Unable to update WorkflowMilestone record.");
            return workflowMilestone;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

You can see the model that is being used here: http://pastebin.com/qACfrNnV

Since a POST request works fine, I could use that, but I would rather stick to the standard and use a PUT.

I have researched for a solution to this for several hours without success.  I would appreciate any ideas on what I could be doing wrong here.  Thank you.

Comment: So, this error you're getting.  Is it on the server side or the client side?

Comment: It is coming from the Server side.

Comment: The first thing I would try is to use a known REST test tool, like SoapUI or Google Chrome's REST Console.  See if you're able to reproduce it using those tools.  The JSON looks fine to me.  Do you have any custom annotations on your model object?  Could you perhaps post your model?

Comment: There isn't any real special annotations in the model. You can see it here: http://pastebin.com/qACfrNnV